# Deleting Pointer Causing Debug Assert

Tags: c++, pointers, memory, memory-management

I've been working on a memory pool allocator class, and no major problems have arisen, sans Visual Studio's debug assertion (_BLOCK_TYPE_IS_VALID(pHead->nBlockUse)) being thrown whenever I try to free the memory allocated by `new` with `delete`.

```
typedef uintptr_t   uptr;
typedef uint8_t     u8;
typedef uint16_t    u16;
typedef uint32_t    u32;
typedef uint64_t    u64;
typedef int8_t      s8;
typedef int16_t     s16;
typedef int32_t     s32;
typedef int64_t     s64;

struct FreeList
{
    FreeList *next;
};

template<class T, u8 alignment, u32 poolSize>
class PoolAllocator
{
private:
    u8          _paddedSize;    // The size in bytes of each allocated chunk of memory. 
    u32         _numAllocations;// The number of allocations made by the pool.          
    u32         _freeBytes;     // The number of bytes left in the pool.                
    u32         _usedBytes;     // The number of bytes currently occupied in the pool.  
    FreeList*   _freeListHead;  // A pointer to a freed space in memory.                
public:
    PoolAllocator() :
        _paddedSize((sizeof(T) > sizeof(uptr) ? sizeof(T) : sizeof(uptr))),
        _numAllocations(0),
        _freeBytes(0),
        _usedBytes(0),
        _freeListHead(nullptr)
    {
        _freeListHead = reinterpret_cast<FreeList*>(operator new (_paddedSize * poolSize));
        _freeBytes = _paddedSize * poolSize;

        uptr current = reinterpret_cast<uptr>(_freeListHead);
        uptr last = current + (_paddedSize * poolSize);
        for (int i = 0; i < poolSize-1; i++)
        {
            uptr next = current + _paddedSize;
            (reinterpret_cast<FreeList*>(current))->next = reinterpret_cast<FreeList*>(next);
            current += _paddedSize;
        }
        reinterpret_cast<FreeList*>(current)->next = nullptr;
    }
    T *allocate()
    {
        if (_freeListHead != nullptr && _freeBytes >= _paddedSize)  // Make sure the pool has memory left
        {
            uptr *toReturn = reinterpret_cast<uptr*>(_freeListHead);    // Cast the pointer to a modifiable data type.
            _freeListHead = _freeListHead->next;    // VITAL THAT THIS IS BEFORE SETTING DATA TO 0.
            *toReturn = 0;  // Set the data at the memory location to 0.

            _freeBytes -= _paddedSize;
            _usedBytes += _paddedSize;
            _numAllocations++;

            printf("Allocated %d bytes of memory at %p.\n", _paddedSize, toReturn);
            return reinterpret_cast<T*>(toReturn);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Pool allocator out of memory! Returning nullptr.\n");
            return nullptr;
        }
    }
    void free(T **ptr)
    {
        FreeList *newHead = reinterpret_cast<FreeList*>(*ptr);
        *ptr = nullptr;
        newHead->next = _freeListHead;
        _freeListHead = newHead;

        _freeBytes += _paddedSize;
        _usedBytes -= _paddedSize;
        _numAllocations--;
        printf("Freed %d bytes of memory at %p.\n", _paddedSize, _freeListHead);
    }
    void clear()
    {
        assert(_usedBytes == 0);

        FreeList *head = _freeListHead;
        while (head != 0)
        {
            FreeList *next = head->next;
            delete reinterpret_cast<T*>(head);
            head = next;
        }

        _paddedSize = 0;
        _numAllocations = 0;
        _freeBytes = 0;
        _usedBytes = 0;
        _freeListHead = nullptr;
    }
};
```

The test code I am using:

```
int main()
{
    PoolAllocator<int, 4, 4> pool;
    int *a, *b, *c, *d, *e;

    a = pool.allocate();
    b = pool.allocate();
    c = pool.allocate();
    d = pool.allocate();
    pool.free(&a);
    e = pool.allocate();

    printf("A | %p\t%d\nB | %p\t%d\nC | %p\t%d\nD | %p\t%d\nE | %p\t%d\n", a, 0, b, *b, c, *c, d, *d, e, *e);

    pool.free(&b);
    pool.free(&c);
    pool.free(&d);
    pool.free(&e);
    pool.clear();

    return 0;
}
```

The problem area lies here:

```
void clear()
{
    assert(_usedBytes == 0);

    FreeList *head = _freeListHead;
    while (head != 0)
    {
        FreeList *next = head->next;
        delete reinterpret_cast<T*>(head); // Debug assert
        head = next;
    }

    _paddedSize = 0;
    _numAllocations = 0;
    _freeBytes = 0;
    _usedBytes = 0;
    _freeListHead = nullptr;
}
```

What this code is supposed to do is increment through the linked list of memory locations where individual pieces of data of type T are being stored. My reasoning for this being a valid piece of code is that, because the initially allocated memory is divided into pieces the size of `sizeof(T)`. Therefor, I assumed that it would be appropriate to typecast the memory address to a pointer of type `T*` so that the individual block of memory would be completely deallocated. This would be done for the entire linked list, ensuring that all allocated memory is freed. However, when I run the code, it always throws the assert on the delete.

Stepping through the code showed that after the first iteration of typecasting and `delete`ing, the pointers take on strange values (the `next` variable, for instance:

> next  0x004b2864 {next=0xfeeefeee {next=??? } }   FreeList *

Whereas before, it was

> next  0x006c2864 {next=0x006c2860 {next=0x006c285c {next=0x00000000
>    } } }  FreeList *

just as it should be). I have tried this approach many different times in many different ways, including typecasting to `void*` instead of `T*`.

This problem has had me stumped for days, and any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Print the address obtained from new, then print the address you are deleting.  Are they the same?  If not, there's your problem.

Comment: Please post `FreeList`.  You can't expect someone to just eyeball your code and tell you what's wrong.  Post the required classes so that others can run the program and determine what the issue is.

Comment: @caveman Just stepped through the debugger again, paying close attention to the addresses. `e` had the address of 0x00672858 prior to the delete. Since it was the final address added to the Free List, it was at the head, which was confirmed by the first iteration of `clear()`'s `head` variable having the same address as `e` (0x00672858), so the problem doesn't appear to lie there.

Comment: You should be calling `head->~T()`, because the memory is allocated using placement new.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Added the FreeList definition at the top of the first code block.

Comment: If you are using linux, run your program under [**valgrind**](http://valgrind.org) after compiling it with debugging symbols.

Comment: @Aunvre What is `uptr`?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Added the typedefs for all `uptr` and all the other data types. To answer you specifically, it's a 4-byte unsigned integer that can store a memory address. It's very convenient when incrementing them.

@iharob I am not, unfortunately, on Linux; I'm running VS2013 with [VLD](https://vld.codeplex.com/) on Windows 7

Comment: You probably didn't unit test your code, since the following simple program shows the same issue:   `a = pool.allocate(); pool.free(&a); pool.clear();`

Comment: almost 'never' write any variable that begins with a '_'.  This is just begging the compiler to have problems (although modern compilers are a lot better in that regard) as the compiler will generate names with a '_' prepended to the variable names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
reinterpret_cast<T*>(head)->~T();
```

I tested this and not getting the assert anymore by replacing  delete reinterpret_cast(head);

You can't call delete on head because the memory wasn't allocated by calling new T();

Answer (score 0):

This will not compile:

```
struct FreeList
{
    FreeList *next;
};
```

... but the following will:

```
struct FreeList
{
    struct FreeList *next;
};
```

Otherwise, an error about incomplete struct definition or unknown type `FreeList` will be raised by the compiler.